# Is there a way to make the position-bounding-box from MatMenu Angular Materials Component to be fixed under the button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay

For example, when you scroll to the edge of the page, it automatically makes the drop menu above the button because there is not enough space below. Is there a way to force it to stay below it.

Comment: Wouldn't the menu be cut off if there is not enough space? What are you trying to achieve? There are the xPosition and yPosition properties to define the default position of the menu. But I am not sure if you can force your desired behavior.

Comment: @JB17 Is there a way to know what the the position the mat-menu is currently on? Right now it shows the default positions but sometimes it changes based on the page break and goes above the buttons. I added a caret to the menu but when the menu list goes above the button it is pointed in the wrong direction.

Comment: Maybe do some research about the UX implementation of menu-buttons. I think that it is fine or even desired behavior that the caret points downwards. It just signals that the menu is opened or closed imo.

Answer (score 0):

**Important** This answer try to solve the question of the "direction" of the icons, **not** force the menu it's showed always below

You can define a class like

```
  .icon-up .dropdown span::after
  {
      transform:rotate(180deg)
  }
```

The dificult is know when you need add this class or not

If your expect a well-know min distance you can create an observable when  windows scroll/resize

```
  export const MENU_SIZE=100

  ViewChild('menu') menu:ElementRef;

  isUp$ = merge(
    fromEvent(window, 'resize'),
    fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
  ).pipe(
    startWith(null),
    debounceTime(100),
    map(
      (_) =>
        window.innerHeight -
          this.menu?.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <
        MENU_SIZE
    )
  );
```

And you enclosed your menu in a div (I use the template reference "#menu")

```
<div #menu [class.icon-up]="isUp$ |async">..</div>
```

Well, we can improve a bit the code making a "generous" MENU_SIZE and force the menu is showed up even if there're enought space below to show the correct icon.

enclosed all in a ng-container with `*ngIf="{data:isUp$} as isUp}"`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{data:isUp$ |async} as isUp">
  <div #menu [class.icon-up]="isUp.data">
     <mat-menu [yPosition]="isUp.data?'above':'below'">
        ...
     </mat-menu>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v2cqhj-emcfzt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.ts) are a stackblitz (really I completed a stackblitz of another question about a create a menu from service adding the part of the icons). It's only to help to see the above code working.

Well we can force more using

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to handle this for `MatMenu`. See [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e2ba68acc279a8b077eaecb189eb574d3c9b8bc3/src/material/menu/menu-trigger.ts#L484) - the `PositionStrategy` (which is responsible for where the overlay is displayed, is not injected, but is hard-coded. Which makes absolute sense, since showing an overlay which contents will be off-screen doesn't make much sense in the first place.

You could create a custom menu using `CdkOverlay` (docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview)) to create the overlay, apply the `PositionStrategy` of your choice that will behave the you want to it, and then insert the menu contents into the overlay. As of version 14, Material CDK offers a a bunch of stuff related to making customer menus -  `CdkMenu` (docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/overview)).